# JavaScript: get date difference and convert months to years

Tags: javascript, date, math

If given two dates in the MM/YY format how can I get the difference in years and months alone using a function.

Example: the result of 03/10 & 01/14 would be 3 years and 10 months.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A bit of simple math. What have you tried?

Comment: Be sure to actually attempt something before asking for help here. Once you write some code and run into a problem, then we can assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse the date and calculate it with milliseconds, but this is a quicker way.

```
var date1 = "03/10".split("/");
var date2 = "01/14".split("/");
var months = date2[0] - date1[0] + 12 * (date2[1] - date1[1]);
var result = Math.round(months / 12) + " years " + (months % 12) + " months";
```

You can swap the date strings on the first 2 lines with your variables, and you should be able to guess where you get the years and months out as numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend [momentjs](http://momentjs.com) for date manipulation in JavaScript.

```
var start  = moment("03/10", "MM/YY"),
    finish = moment("01/14", "MM/YY");

var diff     = finish.diff(start),
    duration = moment.duration(diff);

duration.years();  // 3
duration.months(); // 10
```

Enjoy momentjs. It makes your life so easy.

Comment: To be clear: dealing with dates in javascript by yourself will make you very sad, very quickly.