# How do I get months and years between start date and end date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for the solution for while, but i didn't get what i except.

Case : Start Date : `10/17/2017` and End Date: `02/23/2018`
      From these date range I want to get months and years in a array format like following

```
      array 1
      - 2017
         -10
         -11
         -12
      array 2
      - 2018
         -01
         -02
```

Please let me know your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you not using a Date object to store dates? You could use the moment JS library to do something matching your description - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21293157/2344348 .

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/21293157/2344348

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: get date difference and convert months to years](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293046/javascript-get-date-difference-and-convert-months-to-years)

Comment: @PraveenKumar - that is not returning an array of months - neither is Woodrow's "duplicate"

Comment: @mplungjan I thought that might give some starting point. What say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was intrigued so I wrote it anyway - might as well post it. Moment.js is huge overkill here.

```js
var obj = {}, start=new Date("10/17/2017"), end=new Date("02/23/2018");
for (var i=start.getTime(), n = end.getTime(); i<=n;) { // we update i later
  var d=new Date(i), year = d.getFullYear(), month=d.getMonth()+1;
  if (!obj[year]) obj[year] = [month]; // initialise array
  else obj[year].push(month); // add to array
  d.setMonth(month); // next month
  i = d.getTime();   // here instead of in the for statement
} 
console.log(obj);
```